# read googlesheets with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a asp.net VB app. that reads my googlesheets and captures the sheet data. I have gone thru the signup process and have been able to get to my googlesheets and list the title name. Now I want to read a range of a sheet and save/print the data in each field of the sheet.

Here is the code I use to read the titles: Any help on this would be great.

```
    Dim CLIENT_ID As String = "xxxxxxxx-uqendrdt7cp8ko779q8tvrcogqrsg04c.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    Dim CLIENT_SECRET As String = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    Dim SCOPE As String = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds"
    Dim REDIRECT_URI As String = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"

    Dim parameters As New OAuth2Parameters()
    parameters.ClientId = CLIENT_ID
    parameters.ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
    parameters.RedirectUri = REDIRECT_URI
    parameters.Scope = SCOPE

    Try
        Dim authorizationUrl As String = OAuthUtil.CreateOAuth2AuthorizationUrl(parameters)
        parameters.AccessCode = "xxxxxxxxxx"
        OAuthUtil.GetAccessToken(parameters)
        Dim accessToken As String = parameters.AccessToken

        Dim requestFactory As New GOAuth2RequestFactory(Nothing, "MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1", parameters)
        Dim service As New SpreadsheetsService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1")
        service.RequestFactory = requestFactory
        Dim query As New SpreadsheetQuery()
        query.Title = ""

        Dim feed As SpreadsheetFeed = service.Query(query)
        ' Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
        For Each entry As SpreadsheetEntry In feed.Entries
            ' Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen
            Response.Write(entry.Title.Text)
            Response.Write("<br><br>")

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred ", ex.Message))
    End Try
```

Comment: What specifically are you having an issue with?

Comment: I am trying to read the row/column detail data but not sure how to access the row/column in the googlesheet. How do I reference the row/column in VB?

Comment: Have you had a look at this: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get ?

Comment: Yes I have, but have not found a way or answer to read the row/colums data. I couldn't find any examples to do this in either VB or C+. But thanks for your help so far.